# openai::API::SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE

Tags: ssl, openssl, openai-api

```
import openai
import requests
from requests.exceptions import RequestException
import sys
# Set your OpenAI API key
openai.api_key = 'put your key'
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
response = openai.Completion.create(
    engine="davinci-codex",
    prompt="What is the meaning of life?",
    max_tokens=50,
    verify=False  # Disable SSL verification
)
print(response.choices[0].text.strip())
```

openai.error.APIConnectionError: Error communicating with OpenAI:
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.openai.com', port=443): Max retries
exceeded with url: /v1/engines/davinci-codex/completions (Caused by
SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3
alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:1129)')))

not getting response from openai

```
 openssl s_client -connect api.openai.com:443 -tls1_3
```

```
$ openssl  s_client -connect api.openai.com:443 -tls1_2
CONNECTED(00000194)
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 217 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1710155172
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
---
5000:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:../openssl-1.1.1p/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1543:SSL alert number 40
```

why handshake failure is not clear ?